# how to find id by class name python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
<input class="select_step ON " id="step_9285985_select" name="step_9285985_select" type="checkbox" value="9285985">
```

I am automating the regular tasks of our project by python selenium. struct at one step, Please help me.

As per the above html code `id="step_9285985_select"` randomly changing for every time browser opens through `webdriver` (python Selenium). I want to find the randomly generated `"id"` by the `class="select_step ON` or any other alternative.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to accept and answer by selecting the grey tick mark next to an answer. Users take time to answer questions and the least we can do is to reward them with reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

First find the element by CSS selector:

```
input_tag = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.select_step.ON')
```

Then get the `id` attribute:

```
print(input_tag.get_attribute('id'))
```